# Inserting rows on a static UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to add a row to a static table, but I'm getting this error:

`2015-05-31 13:53:13.153 notify[30565:6091085] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'`

I have an @IBAction (connected to a UINavigationItem) to add the row:

```
@IBAction func addRow(sender: AnyObject) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowCount, inSection: 0)
    rowCount += 1
    rowAdded = true

    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
}
```

with attributes for the rowCount (default in the IB design), and a bool to work out if the next row has been added yet:

```
class NotifyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  var rowCount = 2
  var rowAdded = false
  ...
}
```

The table has 1 section, and its `numberOfRowsInSection:` method I've added:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  if rowAdded {
    return 3
  }else {
    return 2
  }
}
```

and finally, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell") as? UITableViewCell

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "customCell")
            cell.textLabel!.text = "New Cell"
        }

        return cell
    }else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

I've tried wrapping the insertRowsAtIndexPaths call in begin/endUpdates, but I get the same error. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: what kind of strange shenanigans are you doing here? Why are you only specifying the cell for the 3rd row? Why are you not just returning the rowCount in the numberOfRowsInSection? And where exactly does it the crash occur - in what line?

Comment: Static `UITableView`s do not support adding rows. They are static for a reason.

Comment: @luk2302 I could just increment the rowCount and return that, yep. That won't resolve the crash though; here's the full output http://pastebin.com/ADJ8sY4S

Comment: You're not supposed to implement any of the table view data source methods for a table view with static cells.

Comment: Static table views are meant to be, wait for it, static. They don't support adding or removing cells. In my experience, the only thing that's worth doing before it's more tedious that making a dynamic table view is to hide the last cells in a section. What you could do is to add that cell in your storyboard, and return a smaller number in `numberOfRowsForSection:`. Anything more than that is more trouble than making it a dynamic table view.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to add rows to a static table I also needed to implement
`intentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let path = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: indexPath.section)
        return super.tableView(tableView, indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath: path)
    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        return 42
    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```